# DROP packets (instead of REJECT) from specific port when no application is listening?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with `iptables`.

I want that attackers would see a consistent state when trying to map my ports.
I want all my ports to appear as filtered (i.e., drop everything).
However, some applications need a specific open port when I'm using them.

I would like that for this specific port, the firewall will drop everything if there is no application listening on that port (instead of replying with reject).
And allow everything if there is an application that is listening.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not aware of a single/simple `iptables` rule to have it open/close a port based on a service actually listening on that port, you can achieve what you need by changing the default `iptables` policy to `DROP` and allow **only** the ports you need.

For example, say you have `sshd` listening on `port 22` and `apache2` on `port 80` (**don't do this if connected via ssh!**)

```
# Start with empty tables
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Change INPUT policy to DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP

# Make sure the machine itself can connect to the internet
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Maybe allow ICMP's echo/reply (i.e. ping)
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# Add ports for which there are services listening
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

This way, **for every port but 22 and 80**, `iptables` *drops* the packets.

If you need a new port open, just add ("append") a new rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport NN -j ACCEPT
```

If you don't need a port anymore, delete the relevant rule

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If you want a sort of automatic allowing/denying based on services (it looks so from your question), you can always have a basic `iptables` ruleset and then modify your services' scripts to append (-A) the relevant rule on *startup* and delete it (-D) on *stop*.

Comment: So the answer my question is no?

Comment: @LiranFunaro it's _yes_. While you cannot use a "static" `iptable` rule to automagically open/close a port, you can dynamically insert and delete a rule on a per-need basis while keeping a _default_ DROP policy **for all ports** so they appear as "filtered" on port scanning and such.

Comment: "While you cannot use a "static" iptable rule to automatically open/close a port": That is the answer I was looking for. Thanks. I suggest inserting it to your answer.